# Minifying with Google Closure Compiler an AngularJs app written in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, google-closure-compiler

I've been writing an AngularJs app using Typescript in Visual Studio. Typescript compiles all files into a single file on build. We've added a post-build step on release for the google closure compiler to minify the single file output. Any option other than WHITESPACE_ONLY on --compilation_level parameter causes the application to fail to initialize. the nested module names for example of my.module.name { } become function(a){ function(a) { function (a) { when minified. this is causing an angular error when it's injecting in typescript the final injection entry is a "modulename.classname" reference. AngularJs fails to initiate this minified as it becomes a.classname. See below example of how it's written, and how it's minified.
myApp is in a my.module module, and the controller is in a sub-module called my.module.name

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", "myService", "myService2", name.myControllerClass]);
```

this works fine if we understand that myControllerClass is a class that's written as a controller, in the my.module.name module in a .ts file. (it's all referenced fine too, and works when not minified)

when minified with anything other than WHITESPACE_ONLY the output becomes:

```
(function(a){(function(a){var d=angular.module("MyModule",[]);
d.controller("myController", ["$scope", "myService", "myService2", a.myControllerClass]);
```

angular fails to initialise saying that a doesn't contain myControllerClass. It makes sense as a in this instance would be "my.module" not "my.module.name"

Has anyone come across this before and does anyone know a solution that allows minification past "WHITESPACE_ONLY" which is kind of not good enough for our situation. It doesn't have to be google closure compiler that is minifying, but minification of our typescripted angularJs application output is a necessity. It seems like a Typescript minification issue for how it outputs its namespaced module stuff, and then how a minifier interprets it but I'm not sure.

Comment: add `ng-strict-di` to the HTML with your `ng-app`, eg.  `<body ng=app="myApp" ng-strict-di>`.  This will cause angular to perform additional checks and warnings relating to Dependency Injection, which will likely highlight the problem areas to fix.  There isn't anything specifically wrong with doing `modulename.classname`, even when minified;  it *sounds* like `modulename` isn't being injected somewhere.

Comment: Do you need minification or obfuscation? What kind of level of minification do you need besides removing whitespace? Another option might be to use [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). PS: aren't you missing part of your output? What you supplied isn't even valid JS. What is the input of the variable `a` in both cases?

Comment: @Claies I dont know if you want to post that as an answer or not, but you hit the nail right on the head, adding that Directive showed up a single myApp.config() that did not annotate its injections correctly. After correcting that the SIMPLE compilation level minification works and angular can initialise properly. Damn I wish i knew that Directive earlier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular framework provides a specialty directive that is designed to help identify potential issues with [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di): `ng-strict-di`.

> Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations.

Adding the `ng-strict-di` method to your bootstrap, either by including it with `ng-app` (`<body ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>`) or by setting `strictDi: true` when manually bootstrapping will enable strict mode.

Strict mode does not modify the code and is production safe.  Using strict mode allows you to identify potential problem areas with dependency injection which are not minification safe.